# Postfix configuration to receive successful mail delivery notfication

Tags: postfix-mta

I have been using `notify_classes` to receive bounce email notifications, is there a way to receive a successful email delivery notfication by some configuration which can be done on Postfix server.

I know we can add headers in the email to receive delivery notifications but I want to do it on postfix server itself and not via headers.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#notify_classes don't comprise successful delivery.